# query for summing up values present in different columns in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have columns i.e. theory marks, pratical marks, student's Id ,course Id ,& subject Id
i need to add up the vaules present in columns theory marks & practical marks in order to get the aggregate, i dont know how to add the column values though. I am using sql server 2005

please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming theory marks and practical marks are numerical data types

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    course_id,
    subject_id,    
    SUM(theory_marks + practical_marks) AS overall_mark
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    student_id, course_id, subject_id
```

Comment: thank you, that does solve my problem but just for curiousity sake, can you tell me how to do the same thing if the columns were of varchar datetype???

Comment: you need to CAST the column(s) to a numerical datatype. e.g. CAST(myVarCharColumn AS FLOAT). SQL Server will raise an error if a column value cannot be cast. See http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_1.htm

Comment: You can check if a value is numeric before attempting to cast, using ISNUMERIC(myColumn).